# Modify large string

Tags: java, regex

I have a large string in the following format -

```
   <a href="12345.html"><a href="12345.html"><a href="12345.html"><a href="12345.html">
   <a href="12345.html"><a href="12345.html"><a href="12345.html"><a href="12345.html">
```

Id like to store all occurances of the value that occurs before .html. So above html becomes something like 12345.html,12345.html,12345.html,12345.html,12345.html,12345.html,12345.html,12345.html

Do I need a regular expression? or some kind of replace method.

Thanks

Comment: All ocurrences only occurs inside the link tag (a)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need a regular expression, but you could use the underlying Matcher class:

```
final String searchString = "12345.html";
final String txt =
"<a href=\"12345.html\"><a href=\"12345.html\"><a href=\"12345.html\"><a href=\"12345.html\">\n"
+ "<a href=\"12345.html\"><a href=\"12345.html\"><a href=\"12345.html\"><a href=\"12345.html\">";
final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(searchString, Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(txt);
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(matcher.find()){
    if(sb.length() > 0) sb.append(',');
    sb.append(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**Output:**

> 12345.html,12345.html,12345.html,12345.html,12345.html,12345.html,12345.html,12345.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use an HTML parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(yourString);
Elements els = doc.select("a");
for(Element el: els){
    //this only if needs the number without the HTML
    //if not, only el.attr("href")
    if(el.attr("href").contains(".html")){
         String[] parts = el.attr("href").split(".html");
         System.out.println(parts[0]);
    }          
}
```

Don't use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: while I agree that using a parser is better, this doesn't seem to solve the OP's (weird) problem

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd Look at my edited code. This should get all before .html in the links. It was I understand from the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you are accessing this string inside the java code, you can split the string on  "=' delimeter. It will result in a bunch of strings. One string will look like "

So the steps are:
1. split the string which will result in string array.
2. Iterate over the resulting array and look for the pattern ">

Comment: Your post is messed up. Please wrap your literals with backticks like this ` to fix this